# Make pdf-tools remember the page I was on

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, pdf-tools, persistence

How to make pdftools remember the page I was on when I close a PDF document, restart Emacs and reopen the PDF? Some PDF readers after opening a document go to the last page the user was on and don't start from the beginning, I'd like Emacs to do the same.

I tried elisp I found on [Github](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/18) ,none of the snippets work for me. When using the last one I get this error when trying to open a PDF that was previously opened:

> File mode specification error: (error "Buffer is not associated with
>   any file :[parent directory name]")

The PDF opens fine but doesn't go to the bookmarked page, it starts from the beginning.

I also tried bookmark+. It works but I have to remember to set bookmark manually before closing the PDF which is inconvenient.

Comment: workaround https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pdf-view-restore](https://melpa.org/#/pdf-view-restore) works for me and is available on MELPA. But the [pdf-view-restore github page](https://github.com/007kevin/pdf-view-restore) seems to provide more useful configuration instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [saveplace-pdf-view](https://github.com/nicolaisingh/saveplace-pdf-view).