# Adding bookmarks in pdf-tools

Tags: bookmarks, pdf-tools

Is there a way to add and view bookmarks in pdf-tools?
Or else How could I go about adding this feature?

I'm not actually sure if this is even a feature of pdfs.
All I know is I can do this with document viewer app on ubuntu.

Comment: This might direct you in the right direction: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34210/make-pdf-tools-remember-the-page-i-was-on?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

[org-pdftools](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools) is able to set pdf page links, which can then be saved in an org-mode file. Alternatively, if you want to have something embedded in the pdf file, you can add an annotation somewhere on the page (see annotations keybindings [list](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools)), and then list/jump to them via `C-c C-a l` and `SPACE`. I think that these two features are the closest thing that there is to the bookmarks feature in document viewer.